# ASPNET MVC WITH EF- SUM & GROUP BY

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I tried to convert that SQL Query to Link but it does not work.

```
SELECT
SUM([Quantity]) as qt
,[ArticleID]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Location]
Group by ArticleID
Order by qt

List <Location> articles = contexteEF.Location.GroupBy(l => l.ArticleID).Select(a => new { qt = a.Sum(b => b.Quantity), ArticleID = a.Key }).OrderByDescending(a => a.qt).ToList();
```

Can you help me! Please!

Thanks

Comment: **How** does it not work? "It doesn't work" can be anything.

Comment: It shows me this error : 
Can not implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.List<anonymous type int qt, int ArticleID>>' in 'System.Collection.Generic.List<DAL.Location>'

Comment: Please find one of the numerous questions/answers about this exception on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cast a list of dynamic objects to a `List<Location>`

I assume that Location has the properties `qt` and `ArticleId`?  In that case, don't create dynamic objects, create Locations.  Code not tested, but something like:

```
List <Location> articles = contexteEF.Location.GroupBy(l => l.ArticleID).Select(a => new Location() { qt = a.Sum(b => b.Quantity), ArticleID = a.Key }).OrderByDescending(a => a.qt).ToList();
```

Comment: No, The location table contains ArticleID and Quantity

Comment: Not the table, the C# class that you are wanting to get a list of.   Actually I think your problem bay be List<Location> - it's not locations you're wanting, but total quantity of locations of articles, right?

Comment: OK, so you need a class to represent that, with properties ArticleId and, say, SummedLocationQuantity.  Then create objects of that type instead of dynamic objects.  replace "List<Location> articles" with  "var articles"

Comment: var articles = (from c in contexteEF.Location
                            group c by c.ArticleID into result
                            select new LocationEditee
                            {
                                ArticleID = result.Key,
                                Quantity = result.Sum(b => b.Quantity),
                            }).ToList();

Comment: it works now thx ;)

Comment: Anonymous objects are no "dynamic objects". Also, please edit your question to contain the the working code --and formatted.